# Why will using __construct instead of widget_class_name when creating widget trigger out of memory error

Tags: widgets, errors

I find that if I use

```
class widget_name extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() { ... }
}
```

instead of

```
class widget_name extends WP_Widget {
    function widget_name() { ... }
}
```

I get an error like

> `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/klifmedia.net/httpdocs/jm/km/wp-content/themes/km/functions.php on line 77`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `widget_name::__construct()` calls `WP_Widget::WP_Widget()`, which in turn calls `widget_name::__construct()` etc.

A simple solution would be to make `widget_name::__construct()` call `WP_Widget::__construct()` directly.

Also see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16768#comment:9

Comment: You might be looking for `parent::__construct()`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @hakre That's not what the OP was asking about.

Comment: I mean that `widget_name::__construct()` call `parent::__construct()` directly.

Comment: @hakre Oh, I see. Yeah, that might work.